# How to resolve this equation for $f(n)$ without using $f(n-1)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

I have an equation related to some work I'm doing on Poisson distribution where I'm calculating a sequence of 100 values between a minimum and maximum value which is set by another formula. Unfortunately I don't really understand this area of maths, but I'm trying to resolve this equation to use in a computer calculation.

Let $m$ be the minimum value and $M$ be the maximum value (which are given).

$n$, $m$ and $M$ are all integers.
f(n) is also rounded to an integer value.

For $n=1$,
$$
f(n) = \min(m,1)
$$

For values of $1<n\leq100$ this is the formulae
$$\large{
f(n) = \min\Biggl\lgroup\biggl\lgroup\frac{M}{f(n-1)}\biggr\rgroup^{\frac{1}{101-n}} \cdot (n-1) , n\Biggr\rgroup
}$$

My question is - is there a way to implement this function/equation that doesn't rely on knowing the value of $f(n-1)$ - knowing $n$, $M$, and $m$.

An example sequence for $m=1$, $M=847$ is at http://pastebin.com/PvQgNg7i

Comment: Apologies if my terminology and markup is bad - I've not done proper maths in over 10 years! It's my first question on here, so be gentle :)

Comment: Hey, not bad for someone so rusty!  Anyway, one thing I could suggest is to try a few numerical values out and see how things behave.  This is a tough-looking definition, but maybe there's an underlying pattern.

Comment: What is the nature of the max and min values?  Are they integers, positive integers, or just any old real number?

Comment: @rlgordonma - I can calculate the series in Excel. For $m=1$ & $M=847$, the values are as at http://pastebin.com/PvQgNg7i

Comment: @anorton Good question - $n$, $m$, $M$ and $f(n)$ are all integers. There is some rounding that I've omitted - not sure how to show that. Essentially the first expression in the minimum (everything except the $, n$) is rounded to the nearest integer. Will add that to the question.